# Is there a .NET GDI+ equivalent of Java Swing's SetComposite (for Graphics transparency)?

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+, transparency

I was wondering if there is an equivalent to Swing's SetComposite on the .NET GDI+ Graphics object?

In java I can do something like this:

```
Composite c = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .5f);
g2.setComposite(c);
// everything now gets painted with 50% transparency
```

I know there is `ColorMatrix` but that's only explicitly for transforms on images whereas I'd be looking for something on the entire graphics object.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Not available.  You could draw into a bitmap instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Form transparency, Control transparency which supports transparency

Comment: I didn't think all Controls have transparency as a property and I'm not looking to make the entire Form transparent.